# Como fazer programa em Python rodar em 32 e 64 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Tenho um programa feito em Python(3.5) sob sistema operacional de 64 bits, existe a possibilidade de eu fazer ele rodar em 64 e também em 32 bits no windows?

OBS: Utilizei o Pyinstaller pra compilar o programa pra rodar em maquinas windows que não tenham o python instalado.

Comment: Se for 100% escrito em Python sem dependências de APIs externas vai rodar tranquilamente, você tem que dar mais detalhes para saber aonde esta o seu problema.

Comment: Esse meu programa eu compilei usando o Pyinstaller, pois quero que tambem rode sem ter o python instalado na maquina do usuário. E ele realmente roda normalmente, mas só se a maquina do usuário for 64 bit, se for 32 bit ele não roda.

Comment: se compilar para 32bit no windows ele vai rodar em 32 e 64, se compilar para 64bits só vai rodar no 64. Se for em Linux então tem que criar um executável para cada um.

Comment: hmmm que zica, vou criar uma maquina virtual então com win 32 bit pra poder compilar e testar. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Não precisa de uma maquina virtual, basta instalar o pyinstaller pra 32bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Se criar o executável para 32bit para Windows ele vai rodar em windows32bit e windows64bit.
- Se compilar para Windows 64bits só vai rodar no 64bits
- Se for em Linux então tem que criar um executável para cada distro (debian, fedora, etc) e para cada tipo de processador.

> Só pra constar o Python não é compilado, o que o [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) cria é um executável "standalone" com a aplicação python completa mais o seu `.py` (ou um [**Bytecode**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) dele, não conheço o núcleo para afirmar detalhadamente)
>
> [image: programa standalone gerado]
>
> Veja que o `python.exe` e os `.pyd` vão junto.

### Windows

Se for um executável só para Windows basta instalar o [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) para Windows 32bit (x86), creio que para isto primeiro você deve instalar o Python para windows-32bit e depois instalar o `pip` nele, em seguida instale:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Tome cuidado que se tiver múltiplas versões do Python é melhor apontar o caminho inteiro do Python antes de rodar o `pip` e o `pyinstaller`, recomendo que leia isto: [PIP work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

Comment: Certo, vou tentar aqui então instalando o python de 32 bit, obrigado.

Comment: Sim vão sim, mas se eu usar no final do comando o "--onefile" ele compila tudo dentro do executavel, aí fica tudo lá dentro.

Comment: Consegui fazer rodar no 32 e 64 bit agora, seguindo a dica que vc deu, agora ta rodando legal. Obrigado pela ajuda =)